# warning: [deprecation] TYPE_MOBILE in ConnectivityManager has been deprecated?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.aniketjain.weatherapp.network;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;


public class InternetConnectivity {
    public static boolean isInternetConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean connection_flag = false;
        if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            connection_flag = true;
        }
        return connection_flag;
    }
}


warning: [deprecation] TYPE_MOBILE in ConnectivityManager has been deprecated
        if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
```

Comment: The error is very clear, look at the manual/documentation and find a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example to use for:

```
val isNetworkAvailable = (context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager).run {
    getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork)?.run {
        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                || hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                || hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)
    } ?: false
}
```

If you aim to use `TYPE_MOBILE` for older version, you can add check on above for API level:
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
This has been deprecated in API level 28.

[image: Screenshot]

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#TYPE_MOBILE)

You can see that there is a suggestion on what you should use instead:

> Applications should instead use NetworkCapabilities#hasTransport or
> requestNetwork(android.net.NetworkRequest,
> android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) to request an
> appropriate network. See NetworkCapabilities for supported transports.

Comment: I don't know how to use  Applications should instead use NetworkCapabilities#hasTransport or requestNetwork(android.net.NetworkRequest, android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) to request an appropriate network. See NetworkCapabilities for supported transports.

Comment: @Airat72 - A simple google search can help you with that.